# Looking for National Geographic basemaps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, basemap

I need to use National Geographic mapping for a project. I'm unable to find any documentation on how to actually get the basemap into QGIS. How can I do this?

Comment: To get ESRI:s version of one you can [do this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find two ESRI versions of National Geographic maps in the [Quick Map Services](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices) plugin.

After installing the plugin, open the search window using `"Web > QuickMapServices > Search QMS"` and search for *"National Geographic"*.

[image]